# How do I extend a NSManagedObject to contain MKAnnotation in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, mapkit

I have a Photo class

```
class Photo: NSManagedObject {
}
```

I want to extend it to provide MKAnnotation

I tried doing it so by

```
extension Photo: MKAnnotation  {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

However the compiler complains that extensions cannot have stored properties.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have stored properties, but you can have calculated properties!

I.e:

```
var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    get {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.0, longitude: 10.0)
    }
}
```