# Create an array of CLLocation coordinates from Core Data

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, cllocation

Perhaps I can't find an answer to this question because it's something so very simple that I should be able to figure it out, but I'm stumped. Oh, and apologies if some of my terminology is off - I'm still learning.

I'm using Swift and have an array derived from Core Data. So far, so good. Two elements within this array are Doubles/NSNumbers storing latitude and longitude. I'll be using these two elements to draw on to a map, but I can't figure out how to get these two into an array of CLLocations of their own.

So, I've got my array of all the data in Core Data:

```
var locationsList: [Locations] = []

 var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "game = %d", passedGameNumber)
    request.predicate = pred
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"time", ascending: false)]
    self.locationsList = context.executeFetchRequest(requestMap, error: nil)! as [Locations]
```

But it holds data from everything in Core Data (filtered by game):

```
class Locations: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var game: NSNumber
@NSManaged var time: NSDate
@NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber
@NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber

}
```

And I only need an array containing latitude and longitude, which I will need to convert to CLLocation to put on a map. I should have the map part figured out - it's just this array that has me scratching my head! Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear why you "need to convert to CLLocation to put on a map".  If the map is an MKMapView, it wants objects that implement the MKAnnotation protocol.  Technically, CLLocation does not conform to MKAnnotation but it happens to have a coordinate property which "works" for the map view.

Comment: Thanks Anna. So I don't necessarily need to do any converting of the data? I guess that makes things easier, although I'm still not sure how to take the coordinates I have in Core Data and put them into the MapView. As I understand it, I need an array of just coordinate information, whereas my current dump of data from Core Data also contains the game and time information. As I say, I'm sure there's a very easy answer to this, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Instead of CLLocation, use a class that formally implements MKAnnotation like the built-in MKPointAnnotation.  Even better would be (I think) to just have your Locations class implement the MKAnnotation protocol itself so no new array is needed (you can then give the map view a Locations object to add).  Declare that Locations implements MKAnnotation (as well as NSManagedObject) and then implement a getter method for `coordinate`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995094/how-do-i-extend-a-nsmanagedobject-to-contain-mkannotation-in-swift.  Not sure if you really need to implement as an extension but it gives the idea.  Disclaimer: I have not tried this.

Comment: I shall give it a go! Thanks, Anna.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. On top of a for loop for iterating through the Core Data array, I also had to convert my latitude and longitudes to Doubles before appending them to my new array as CLLocationCoordinate2D.

```
var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

for index in 0..<self.locationsList.count{
        var lat = Double(self.locationsList[index].latitude)
        var long = Double(self.locationsList[index].longitude)
        var coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        coordinates.append(coordinatesToAppend)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Good solution Adam...I was able to do something similar like this..

Declare these global variables

```
 var longitudeCollection: [String] = [String]()
 var latitudeCollection: [String] = [String]()
```

Make an extension to easily access CLLoationDegrees type as a Double

```
extension String {
var coordinateValue: CLLocationDegrees {
    return (self as NSString).doubleValue
    }
}
```

Then this is how you would append the coordinates

```
for var index = 0; index<=longitudeCollection.count-1; index++ {
  var lat = latitudeCollection[index].coordinateValue
  var long = longitudeCollection[index].coordinateValue

  var coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
  coordinates.append(coordinatesToAppend)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use NSNumber to store latitude and longitude points. You can store CLLocation directly to core data instead.

Set up an entity for each CLLocation, it'll be a too-many relation off whatever entity is using location points. Let's call this LocationPoint:

```
class LocationPoint: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var game: NSNumber
@NSManaged var time: NSDate
@NSManaged var location: AnyObject

}
```

You then set the *location* property to transformable in the Xcode data model. That's it!

In Objective-c you can actually still declare this LocationPoint property as CLLocation without any errors:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *location
```